# Function not firing in a location triggered notifications app

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swiftui

I have a little app using SwiftUI and location triggered notifications.

I got started with [this project](https://medium.com/@jonathan2457/location-triggered-notifications-on-ios-24033919fb9a) as far as the location triggered notifications part is concerned.

It is already working quite well and I have notifications firing where I expect them, but there is one thing which I don't understand.

The function *userNotificationCenter:didReceive:withCompletionHandler* does not seem to fire at any time. This is the code for the function in case that may be useful, though it can only ring a bell for people who know the project.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if response.notification.request.identifier == "nyc_promenade_notification_id" {
        let notificationData = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        let message = "You have reached \(notificationData["location"] ?? "your location!")"
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!",
                                                message: message,
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Here is some additional information.

To be precise, I first made the assumption the *userNotificationCenter:didReceive:withCompletionHandler* method was called at some point. Without knowing if it was to be called explicitly or in the background by some framework. But here is what I can now say:

- No explicit call to the function appears in the source of my project, neither in the [GitHub project which I used as a starting point](https://github.com/jgsamudio/LocationNotifier).
- When I want to use the debugger to catch a passing through the method, I get nothing.
- I also tried to put some trace (leaving some logs in a DB) in case the function would be called while walking and entering a given area. But this also led to nothing.

As a result I am not even sure this method is called (or supposed to be called).

In the end, if it is not meant to be fired. I will still have to figure out how and where I can take some action, on entering (or leaving) a given area (i.e. circular region).

Finally, here is the function fired when I decide to set a location based notification.

```
func requestNotification(notificationInfo: LocationNotificationInfo) {
    let notification = notificationContent(notificationInfo: notificationInfo),
    destRegion = destinationRegion(notificationInfo: notificationInfo)

    let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: destRegion, repeats: false),
    request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationInfo.notificationId,
                                    content: notification, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {
        [weak self] (error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.delegate?.notificationScheduled(error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you requesting location notifications? You should be using Core Location to create geofences. Those won't send you user notifications. Search for "Define and Monitor a Geographic Region" and "Handling Location Events in the Background" in the Xcode docs for info on how to request and receive location updates.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the comment. This is my first app to use notifications based on location so I am no expert, but nevertheless I am already receiving location triggered notifications in my app. Following the method used in the project I mentioned.

Comment: So edit your question to show us the code that sets up the notifications.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of something else (Where you use Core Location to have your CODE notified when the user enters/exits a location region. It looks like you are instead creating a `UNLocationNotificationTrigger`, which triggers a local notification based on the user entering a location region. Edit your question to sho the code that sets up the notification trigger.

Comment: @Duncan C; I just made an update to my post, hoping to make my problem clearer. I think I guess what you mean by your last comment, without being totally confident. For the current matter I am not fully aware of the various routes to reach the same result. You are basically referring to two ways to more ore less do the same thing. Right?

Comment: Don't just post a link to a medium article. Post the code you wrote that subscribes to location notifications.

Comment: @Duncan C; I have added a function at the end of the post, hoping this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Having no suggestion from any expert on the matter, I decided to make "a big test".

For that I recompiled the app, commenting out the function:

```
/*func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
.......
}*/
```

To see what would happen.

The result is that the app kept working as usual. Thus showing the function was not really useful, maybe even useless, at least in the range of my testing.

I hope this will be useful to someone else facing the same question. If you know more about the issue, please comment.